# How to read duration of an FLV file in PHP / through shell command?

Tags: php, linux, flv

How do I determine the length of an FLV file from within PHP or through shell access?

I think a dedicated libraries is available, but I'm really looking for a quicker more direct way.

Answer (score 1):

Read this:

- **[How To Get Video Duration With FFMPEG and PHP](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forums/jw-player/setup-issues-and-embedding/9448/how-to-get-video-duration-with-ffmpeg-and-php)**

Answer (score 1):

You will need a FLV meta reader and AMF parser.

I have ALWAYS used this : 
http://www.tommylacroix.com/2009/06/11/mp4-and-f4v-php-flash-video-meta-data-reader/
:) its really great. It gives lot more things for the FLV. it also allows editing FLV meta

Comment: I know you don't want to use dedicated libraries. But if and when you are ready, flvtool2 will be your best choice (ruby) Much faster  than ffmpeg. FFMPEG can be used when you want to manipulate the files.